# Insert form in CMS - <option> with pages

Tags: php, mysql, forms, content-management-system

I am in dilema all day... I make form and all what I need for CMS, but realy don't know how can I add or edit data on difrent pages... I have 10 pages- 10 files .php with contents, and have set one part cone on pages, where I need to inject data with my form....
I have just one solution, what I tried. It is create data_table for all pages, and create 10form for 10 pages, and then changes table name in code. But it is too much jobs and too much space on website, I need one table for all data...If there any way to set it,pls tell me or give me suggestion.
ps. I looking all round google for exemples, but I don't understand, nowhere I can see problem like this.
Below is the code what I uses for page and form

> code for add form

```
    <?php
@session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {

    header("location: login.php");
}
else {
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert new post</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="dodavanje_artikla1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table align="center" border="10" width="800">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5" bgcolor="#5f9ea0"><h1>Here insert new article</h1></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">Insert title:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="naziv" size="40"></td>
            <td><select>
                <option value="page1.php">p1</option>
                <option value="page2.php">p2</option>
                <option value="page3.php">p3</option>
                <option value="page4.php">p4</option>
                <option value="page5.php">p5</option>
                <option value="page6.php">p6</option>
                <option value="page7.php">p7</option>
                <option value="page8.php">p8</option>
                <option value="page9.php">p9</option>
                <option value="page10.php">p10</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">Insert image:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="image"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">Insert content:</td>
            <td><textarea name="tekst" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish">
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
include "../editori/tinymce.php";
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
include("include/connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $text = $_POST['content'];
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];



    if($title=='' or $text=='')
    {
        echo "<script>alert('One or more field is blank')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if($image_type=="image/jpeg" or $image_type=="image/png" or $image_type=="image/gif")
    {
        if($image_size<=50000)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"images/$image_name");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Image is too large, upload is limited till 50kb')</script>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Type of image is invalid')</script>";
    }
    $query = "insert into artikli1 (title,image,content) values ('$title','$image_name','$text')";
    if(mysql_query($query))
    {
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php?published=Article is published','_self')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

> code for pages where i need to put

```
<div class="post_body">
                    <?php
                    include("include/connection.php");

                    $query = "select * from artikli1";
                    $run = mysql_query($query);
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($run))
                    {
                        $artikli_ID = $row['artikli_ID'];
                        $title= $row['title'];
                        $image = $row['image'];
                        $text = $row['content'];

                        ?>
                    <dt><h5><a href="page.php?id=<?php echo $artikli_ID; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h5></dt>
                     <dt><br /><img src="images/<?php echo $image; ?>" width="100" height="100" /> </dt>
                    <dd><ul><?php echo $text; ?></ul></dd>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="solidline"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You have 10 mysql tables but u want 1? You have 10 php files want to have 1?

Comment: well I have 1 mysql table and 10php files-they are in menu.like submenu. I can solve it if I create 10forms and 10 tables,but need to have 1mysql table and drop list in form with 10 php,like <option>page1.php</option>... and one form like in my code

Comment: When u say 10 tables what do you mean? 10 mysql tables or html tables

Comment: To make it work at the moment you have 10 mysql tables but you want 1

Comment: look I have created in phpmyadmin database and in database i have created 1 mysql table with atributes (ID, title,date,image and content). I tried to create every single mysql table with these parametres for every single page. But I need to have one mysql table like now and put field in form with option, and when i want to upload new post-article, I want to choose on what page want to update,do you understand me now?

Comment: I think so i just have no clue why you have 10 tables if you only want 1. Perhaps best to see it. Language barrier. Make a zip shove it on google drive.

Comment: Seeing it takes your describing it out of the equation

Comment: After some sleep i will look at it in the morning as it is 3am

Comment: thanks, if you see any problem, please tell me.. good sleep

Answer (score 0):

> [SOLVED] Problem

In database i added new row type_article, set varchar and default on NULL

then changed this part of code

```
<td><select name:"lista">
            <option value="page1.php">page1</option>
            <option value="page2.php">page2</option>
            <option value="page3.php">page3</option>
            <option value="page4.php">page4</option>
            <option value="page5.php">page5</option>
            <option value="page6.php">page6</option>
            <option value="page7.php">page7</option>
            <option value="page8.php">page8</option>
            <option value="page9.php">page9</option>
            <option value="page10.php">page10</option>
        </select></td>
```

then added in code $type_articlepart

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$text = $_POST['content'];
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$type_article= $_POST['lista']
```

> then changed next code

```
$query = "insert into artikli1 (title,image,content,type_article) values ('$title','$image_name','$text','$type_article')";
```

> in next code, i'v changed

```
$query = "select * from artikli where type_article='page1'";
                    $run = mysql_query($query);
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($run))
                    {
                        $artikli_ID = $row['artikli_ID'];
                        $title= $row['title'];
                        $image = $row['image'];
                        $text = $row['content'];

                        ?>
```

and include this code on every page where I want to update article.

That is all...